# As-salamu alaykum

Tags: language

According to wikipedia, this means "peace", as in "I won't harm you".

Words, translated, sometimes change.

From what I have gathered, salam does not only include "peace", but also security from third parties, protection.

Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

It means 'Peace be on you' it is a prayer to Allah to protect the subject's life, property and faith from disasters. It doesn't mean 'I won't harm you' or 'I will protect you from others'.